# Label word wrap in RowLayout with other elements

Tags: qt, qml

I have two elements inside of a RowLayout, which I'm trying to fit within the boundaries of my window.

```
Page {
    id: settingsView
    anchors.fill: parent
    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Label {
                text: "This is some long sample text which will definitely be wider than the page width."
                padding: 6
                Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width - timeComboBox.width
                verticalAlignment: timeComboBox.height * 0.5
                wrapMode: Label.WordWrap
            }
            ComboBox {
                id: timeComboBox
                model: ["1", "2", "3"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This page gets pushed onto a StackView(the StackView also `anchors.fill: parent`), but no matter what I do, I cannot make it so that the Label text gets wrapped, and the ComboBox ends up half outside the window boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problem points, I've correct them a bit:

```js
Page {
    id: settingsView
    anchors.fill: parent
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width // this item is not inside Layout so can't have Layout.* attached properties
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true 
            Label {
                text: "This is some long sample text which will definitely be wider than the page width."
                padding: 10
                Layout.fillWidth: true // just fill all the space except the ComboBox
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter // that should be enum, not numerical value
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap // this is Text.* emum, not Label's one
            }
            ComboBox {
                id: timeComboBox
                model: ["1", "2", "3"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer was quite simple, all I had to do was remove `Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width - timeComboBox.width` and replace it with `Layout.fillWidth: true`